# Why can't I get php to write normal arrays to json?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am reading a json file and convertig it into a assoc array. Inside that json are `[]` type arrays that have keys that are a 0-based indexing system. When I try to write the assoc array back to json after removing a value from the `[]` array, it turns the `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` into `{"0": 1, "1": 2, "2": 3, "3": 4, "4": 5, "6": 7, "7": 8}` Does anyone know why it does this? I will include my php code below:

```
<?php
function json_removeItemType($arrayid, $itemid) {
    $json = json_read();
    if($json) {
        echo "<p>json true</p>";
        foreach($json as $key => &$value) {
            echo "<p>in 1st foreach loop</p>";
            if($key == $arrayid) {
                echo "<p>key == arrayid<p>";
                foreach($value as &$v) {
                    echo "<p>In second foreach loop</p>";
                    if($v == $itemid) {
                        echo "<p>unsetting value</p>";
                        unset($v);
                        echo "value unset";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $json = json_write($json);
        if($json) {
            echo "<p>json written</p>";
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function json_write($assoc) {
    try {
        $json = fopen("../data.json", "w");
        echo "<p>" . var_dump($assoc) . "</p>";
        $data = json_encode($assoc);
        echo "<p>$data</p>";
        fwrite($json, $data);
        fclose($json);
        return true;
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
}

function json_read() {
    $file = fopen("../data.json", "r");
    $len = filesize("../data.json");
    $data = fread($file, $len);
    $json = (array) json_decode($data);
    return $json;
}

if(json_removeItemType("1", 7)) {
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}
?>
```

Comment: to work fine with JSON there are built-in [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: I am using them in the json_read() and json_write($json) functions. My problem is that it is somehow reading the "normal" array from the json file as a assoc array, or it is encoding the normal array as an assoc array. either one is a problem

Comment: use `array_values()`` for this